# Meta refresh if no input fields exist on page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refresh, meta-tags, page-refresh

In my Rails 3.2.3 application I have the following code in the application.html.erb to refresh the whole page every 30 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

It works well (it's an internal intranet and we need to make sure everyone is looking at the latest information regardless of how long they have left the page open on their computer) and anything more complex, such as AJAX, feel unnecessary.

What I would like to do is have some kind of 'unless' statement wrapping the meta tag such as:

```
<% unless page.contains('input') %>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<% end %>
```

This would prevent the page refreshing after 30 seconds if the page contains a form input field. As it stands at the moment the page will refresh even if you're halfway through filling in a page.

Is anything like this possible. I realise the above code example would never work, it's purely to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

One possibility is to check what the current page's action is as stated in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F):

```
<% current_page?(:action => 'new') %>
```

but I'm not entirely sure if that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably handle this with a script instead, and remove the `<meta http-equiv='refresh'>` tag.

```
var reloadTime = 30;
body.onload = function() {
  // Reload after 30s if no input tags are found
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("input").length === 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload(true);}, reloadTime);
  }
};
```

If you're using jQuery or another library, append this to the DOM ready functions as in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var reloadTime = 30;
   if ($("input").length === 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload(true);}, reloadTime);
   }  
});
```

Comment: If I'm using jQuery can I leave the original meta tag and then add your second code example to the my existing DOM ready functions, or do I need the first example aswell?

Comment: @dannymcc If already using jQuery, you only need the second code sample, and should remove the original meta refresh tag.

Comment: If I use the second example, where do I set the reload time for pages without an input. Assuming I've removed the original meta refresh tag?

Comment: @dannymcc Sorry - I added it into the jQuery function. You can either set the variable at the start of the function, or just hard-code it in place of `reloadTime` in the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having some difficulty getting this to work in my Rails application. Presumably it goes in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js ?

Comment: @dannymcc Yes, in application.js (as long as application.js is being included on every page, like from an application layout)